# PHP : Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Tags: php, arrays

I am getting an error while accessing elements of an array.

This is my current code:

**1st Method::**

```
var_dump($parent_array->info->gcatname);
```

**Error (1st Method)::**

```
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object
```

**2nd Method::**

```
print_r($parent_array[0]['info']['gcatname']);
```

**Error (2nd Method)::**

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
```

Array is as below:

```
array(1) {
 [0]=>
 array(2) {
  ["is_parent"]=>
    bool(true)
  ["info"]=>
  object(stdClass)#6 (5) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
     ["gcatname"]=>
      string(9) "Swine Flu"
     ["gcatowner"]=>
      string(13) "Vaccine India"
     ["gcatactive"]=>
      string(1) "1"
     ["gcatadded"]=>
      string(19) "2016-05-01 08:30:36"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Square brackets (`[]`) and the key for arrays; `->` for object properties: `print_r($parent_array[0]['info']->gcatname);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply: `$parent_array[0]['info']->gcatname`

```
array(1) {
 [0]=> // array(2) stands for the fact that this element with index 0 is an array with the size '2' and it can only be accesses using []
 array(2) {
  ["is_parent"]=>
    bool(true)
  ["info"]=>// object(stdClass) stands for the fact that this element with index 'info' is an array with the size '5' and it can  be accesses using ['info']
  object(stdClass)#6 (5) {// here you have accessed the object now when you wish to access inside this scope you need to use this ->
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
     ["gcatname"]=>//by using ->gcatname you access the property gcatname of the object
      string(9) "Swine Flu"
     ["gcatowner"]=>
      string(13) "Vaccine India"
     ["gcatactive"]=>
      string(1) "1"
     ["gcatadded"]=>
      string(19) "2016-05-01 08:30:36"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Oops!! so easy.. can you tell me how we can know approach to access array values... as you just posted by just seeing the array,..

Comment: Sure hold on I ll edit my question

Comment: @Gags I have editted you can check

Comment: and that is nice... thumb up